# AMD GPU Issues in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS: "amdgpu bonaire not supported" & "snd hda intel hsw/bdw hd audio hdmi/dp requires binding with gfx driver"

Tags: boot, amd-graphics, amdgpu, ubuntu-drivers, opencl

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and have encountered an issue with my AMD GPU after installing an update prompted by Ubuntu. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this problem.

Here's the background information:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04.2 LTS
- AMD GPU model: Bonaire
- Error message 1 - It displayed on a black screen:

  ```
  amdgpu bonaire not supported in kfd, ubuntu boot error
  ```
- Error message 2- It was displayed after using `nomodeset` in the boot parameters:

  ```
  Snd hda intel hsw/bdw hd audio hdmi/dp requires binding with gfx driver
  ```

Although I have basic knowledge of Ubuntu, I can follow instructions and provide any requested information by running commands.

Here are the steps I have already tried, based on suggestions from the forum:

1. Added `nomodeset quiet splash` to the boot parameters, which led to the second error message mentioned above.
2. Renamed `/etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules.bak`.
3. Checked the renamed file with `dpkg -S /etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules.bak`, but it shows:

   ```
   no path found matching pattern /etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules.bak
   ```
4. Edited the rules file by replacing the double equals for `GROUP` with a single equals.
5. The last action I performed related to the GPU was updating it and
   installing ROCm to try Python Torch. Additionally, in my GRUB configuration, I have the following line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9"
   ```

Please note, I'd like to keep ROCm for my project, but if there is no other way, I'll use my CPU's graphic processing capabilities.

I'm unsure what else to attempt to resolve these issues. Any advice, suggestions, or insights would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the AMD sites, it looks like your card will **not** be supported with Ubuntu 22.04. [see here](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci%3A1002-6658-174b-e258&page=2#status) . That page is not exhaustive, but it documents what users have encountered.

But the page talks about the fglrx driver, which should be installed.

Someone in this forum had a [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/945434/906933) which he could solve by installing the [fglrx driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

Comment: I couldn't find a listing for 22.04, does that mean my gpu is not supported? Thank you for your help

Comment: No not necessarily, since that list may not been updated.  If you have problem starting your card: do you have a UEFI Bios and "Secure Boot" disabled?

Comment: Yes, I use Legacy boot and secure boot is disabled

Comment: And did you install the fglrx drivers?

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I verify that? That being said, I performed a reinstall of the LTS, and it's working , but I haven't installed any driver yet. Do you want me to check any commands?

Comment: I believe the issue had occured after I performed some update, ubuntu gave an install new updates prompt after which this error started showing up

Comment: `inxi -G` will tell us your driver. Copy the answer (text) into your question